# How to pass context variables from multiple view functions to the same template

Tags: django, templates, view

I have a single template that is serviced by multiple view functions. As an example, read_posts() view returns all posts with a GET, add_post() view adds a new post with a POST.

I may have other post actions on the same page, needing more view functions.

Now, each of these view functions need to pass different arguments to the template. E.g. each form might require a different form argument to be passed.

What is the best practice in organizing the multiple arguments to a single template from multiple view functions?

As an example posts.html is the template I use:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>My Django Blog</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{% url 'blog:add_post' %}" method="post">
             {% csrf_token %}
             <p><input type="text" name="title" id="title" /></p>
             <p><input type="textarea" name="text" id="text" /></p>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
        {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <h3>{{ post.pub_date }}</h3>
        {{ post.text }}
        {% endfor %} 
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the views I use:

```
def display_posts(request):
    #All posts
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    sorted_posts = posts.order_by('-pub_date')
    context = { 'posts' : sorted_posts }
    return render(request, 'blog/posts.html', context)

def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        #return HttpResponse('Hello World')
        if form.is_valid():
            post = Post()
            post.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            post.text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            post.pub_date = datetime.now()
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blog:display_posts'))
        else:
            form = PostForm() # An unbound form
    return render(request, "blog:display_posts")
```

As you may see `display_posts()` is the default GET when the page is requested, and `add_post()` handles the http POST, when a new post is created.

Each function is handling a different functionality of the page, and they need different context variables passed to the template. (Note I used context only for `display_posts` just yet)

How do I make sure each function sends a different context to the page, and I organize them properly in the template?

When you handle multiple forms on a page, do you use partial templates for them and %include them in the main page?

Thanks.

Comment: What Django version are you using? If it's 1.3 or up then you can use class-based views which enable you to use class inheritance to reuse code.

Comment: Can you post some simplified code example? why can't you use 2 templates with reused blocks?